# xbrl into google spreadsheets using google script

Tags: xml, google-apps-script, google-sheets, xbrl

Can anybody show me how to get XBRL data into google spreadsheets using google script?

http://www.fossil.com/attachments/en_US/financials/2013/fosl-20130330.xml

here is the link.

```
function XBRLexplore() {
  var target = "http://www.fossil.com/attachments/en_US/financials/2013/fosl-20130330.xml";
  var pageTxt = UrlFetchApp.fetch(target).getContentText();
  var pageDoc = Xml.parse(pageTxt,true);

//var temp=getDivById( pageDoc.getElement(), 'Tag204' );
//var temp=getElementById('Tag204')
}
```

I can't seem to get to "tag204" the first element. not sure how to use the get by id functions correctly.

Comment: What have you tried ? It would help if you post some code of your attempt and seek help on a specific problem you are facing rather than ask "give me the code"

Comment: ha. I would but I don't know how. that's why I'm asking. I just need some starting code. Like what this guy provided here. You can see from my previous posts that I do include what code i have. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14805527/grabbing-table-from-html-using-google-script

Comment: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/xml-service/ provides a start for you

Comment: @DavidF. ok thanks. I just want the first element. It has a "Tag204" for ID. How do i grab that? i've tried the code above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at [previous questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgoogle-apps-script%5D%20xml.parse) about parsing XML documents, since XBRL is an application of XML using a standardized taxonomy of business terms. (Remember - HTML documents are XML with tag, or element, types specific to web page design.)

For example, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16702114/1677912) shows some very basic navigation of xml elements. And you should recall [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16860598/1677912) that explained it in greater detail.

The same techniques apply, but with element types such as `AntidilutiveSecuritiesExcludedFromComputationOfEarningsPerShareAmount` (The element containing `id="Tag204"` is one of these.)

```
<us-gaap:AntidilutiveSecuritiesExcludedFromComputationOfEarningsPerShareAmount id="Tag204" decimals="0" contextRef="D2013Q1" unitRef="Shares">201000</us-gaap:AntidilutiveSecuritiesExcludedFromComputationOfEarningsPerShareAmount>
```

The XML element name consists of two parts, a required name prefixed by an optional namespace. In this case, the namespace is `us-gaap`, which tells us the vocabulary source.

Here's how you could get that one element, using the `getElementByVal()` utility introduced in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16702114/1677912), and write it to a spreadsheet:

```
function xbrl() {
  var target = "http://www.fossil.com/attachments/en_US/financials/2013/fosl-20130330.xml";
  var pageTxt = UrlFetchApp.fetch(target).getContentText();
  var xbrl = Xml.parse(pageTxt,true).getElement();

  var Tag204 =
      getElementByVal( xbrl,
                      'AntidilutiveSecuritiesExcludedFromComputationOfEarningsPerShareAmount',
                      'id',
                      'Tag204' );

  var data = [];
  var row = [];
  var name = Tag204.getName().getLocalName();
  row.push(name);
  var attributes = Tag204.getAttributes();
  for (var j=0; j<attributes.length; j++) {
    row.push(attributes[j].toXmlString())
  }
  data.push(row);

  var sheetId = '---Sheet-Id---';
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sheetId).getSheetByName("XBRL");
  sheet.getRange(1,1,data.length,data[0].length).setValues(data);
}
```

Comment: If I wanted to retrieve all of the data into a google spreadsheet, what's the best way to do it? I'm learning about SOAP, should I use that? or is javascript good enough?

Comment: SOAP is a protocol for exchanging objects (using XML), Javascript is a programming language. You can work with SOAP using Javascript, certainly.

Comment: can you show me a few lines of code to get all the data? I can do the spreadsheet part. I think I can handle that now. I just need a way to most efficiently get the data into a format that I can place into the spreadsheet.

Comment: What I'm essentially trying to do is drop all of the "us-gaap" related elements in one sheet, while dropping all of the "fosl:" elements in another sheet. If you show me how to do one, I can do the other.

Comment: I've flatten the structure. But I'm having trouble with the namespace and local name. quick pointer on how to do it would be appreciated. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18040867/google-script-xml-get-parent