# google script xml get parent?

Tags: xml, google-apps-script, google-sheets, xbrl

I have the following code to download a XBRL file into Google spreadsheet

```
function XBRLexplore() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("0Aiy1DTQRndx6dFZLVDJfRnptbmRFUTM2S2lnUlRfWWd");
var Sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1"); // Activate sheet
var target = "http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/867773/000086777313000052/spwr-20130630.xml";
var pageTxt = UrlFetchApp.fetch(target).getContentText();
var xbrl = Xml.parse(pageTxt,true).getElement()
var test=xbrl.getElements();

var output=[];
for (var i=0;i<test.length;i++){
    var element=test[i]
    var f=[element.contextref,element.id,element.unitref,element.decimals,e=element.Text]
    output[i]=f;
}

Sheet.getRange(1,1,test.length,5).setValues(output);
```

}

this will drop about 1700 row by 5 columns into Google spreadsheet.

However, I want all the of sub elements in object "xbrl" added next to each of the elements.

For example: currently, row 1421 is the following data:

`D2013Q2QTD Fact-456FCC569047499F03F61D8FBE559EC1 shares -3 133973000`

I want it to look like this:
`us-gaap WeightedAverageNumberOfDilutedSharesOutstanding D2013Q2QTD Fact-456FCC569047499F03F61D8FBE559EC1 shares -3 133973000`

adding the namespace `us-gaap` and `WeightedAverageNumberOfDilutedSharesOutstanding` in the first 2 columns

it would be nice if for each element i can use some sort of `getParent()` function then just stick it in the first 2 columns during the loop.

I'm trying to use the `getNamespace()` for each element inside the loop, but it's giving me an error

`var ff=element.getNamespace()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not understand very well how you determine the nodes that need, however, after determining them, you can do the following for the first 2 columns you need:

```
  ...
  var target = "http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/867773/000086777313000052/spwr-20130630.xml";
  var pageTxt = UrlFetchApp.fetch(target).getContentText();
  var xbrl = XmlService.parse(pageTxt);
  var element = xbrl.getRootElement().getChildren()[1420];
  Logger.log(element.getNamespace().getPrefix()); // us-gaap
  Logger.log(element.getName()); // WeightedAverageNumberOfDilutedSharesOutstanding
  ...
```

The new service is accessed using [XmlService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/xml-service/), in contrast to the old service which was simply called [Xml](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/xml/).

**UPDATE**

My experience with [XmlService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/xml-service/) is little, not too sure if you can use wildcards for the search of nodes, a very basic example and probably inefficient can be:

```
  ...
  var ns = 'us-gaap';
  var target = "http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/867773/000086777313000052/spwr-20130630.xml";
  var pageTxt = UrlFetchApp.fetch(target).getContentText();
  var xbrl = XmlService.parse(pageTxt);
  var elements = xbrl.getRootElement().getChildren();
  var el, attr;
  for (var element = 0, len = elements.length; element < len; ++element) {
    el = elements[element];
    if (el.getNamespace().getPrefix() === ns) {
      /* YOUR CODE */
      Logger.log(ns);
      Logger.log(el.getName());
      attr = el.getAttribute('contextRef');
      if(attr) Logger.log(attr.getValue());
    }
  }
  ...
```

Comment: I'm looking to get all content from all nodes. How do you do that? thanks for pointing out the new vs. old xml service. i didn't realize that.

Comment: Can you use wildcards? how do i get just `us-gaap` namespace related elements?

Comment: one last question. thanks for your help. it's be helpful. it's relating to the "contextRef" attribute. In the above example the attribute for the above example is something like "D2012Q2". I know that is defined somewhere in the document. How do I look that contextref up?

Comment: http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1318605/000119312513096241/tsla-20121231.xml  ... try this example. you can see each contextref is some type of reference, i'm looking for the ability to look that up somehow

Comment: I updated the code to get the attribute value. I hope you find it useful.