# Grab table from URL in Google App Script

Tags: google-apps-script

In this [link answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14805527/grabbing-table-from-html-using-google-script) in line 6, how to identify how many `getElement("div")` and `getElements("div")[number]` should be captured from a URL.

This is the [URL](http://www.bseindia.com/markets/equity/EQReports/bulk_deals.aspx?expandable=3) from where I am looking to capture the table.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may want to look into using [import.io](https://import.io), which is a tool specifically for extracting tabular data from web pages, and which has an [Apps Script integration](http://blog.import.io/tech-blog/integrating-importio-with-google-apps-script).

Answer (score 0):

another example could be to pull the table into Sheets and the access the data from within the Sheets.  For example:

```
=importhtml("http://www.tradingeconomics.com/zambia/rating","table",1)
```

This pulls the first table on the particular webpage into the sheet.